# DKIM failure when signing with different domain - header.d ignored

Tags: email, hotmail, dkim, outlook.com

We (sender.org) provide a mail server for a client (example.org) and sign outgoing messages with our private DKIM key (we cannot change the signing domain to the client's domain).

```
Return-Path: bounce@sender.org
From: from@example.org
```

The DKIM signature looks like this:

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; t=1413987605;
    s=default; d=sender.org;
    h=Reply-To:List-Unsubscribe:List-Id:From:To:Message-Id:Subject:Date:MIME-Version;
    bh=ISuMd/He7ct2h8gGuqNPS6u0Knk=;
    b=nLx/atDvwyl28uB6MSXRUoQO2tH0Dr46wn+IPnxioKMGBHlKFAeEArz0VZyvXIIG
    wM35CG8QspFTsRxvbV3Wfqx1+cR+6RIK1ecILXxCegNd3SCcaMao3fJ5IYAbL4yLiHy
    lbDvXPCSLmJ2uYsNG2ZeIkWDLLOG+WUjyzdtEPD8=
```

Gmail, Yahoo and others validate the DKIM signature correctly. However in Microsoft mail services such as Outlook.com or hotmail.com the DKIM validation fails:

```
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 123.456.78.90) 
smtp.mailfrom=bounce@sender.org; dkim=none header.d=example.org; 
x-hmca=none header.id=from@example.org
```

The message says `dkim=none` even though the DKIM signature is in the header of the email. More importantly, the `header.d` is wrongly set to `example.org` whereas it should be `sender.org` - the domain that is signing.

We have tried to add `i=@sender.org` to the DKIM signature and changed the order of the header fields - nothing helped.

**Are we missing something?

Is this a bug in hotmail/Outlook.com?

Is there any solution or other indications on how to solve this?**

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate on ServerFault.

Comment: Note that the signature tag is reserved for method signatures.

Comment: @owlstead I am afraid I don't quite understand what you mean. Are you talking about `DKIM-Signature:` in the head?

Comment: Ah, sorry, no the **tag** [tag:signature] is reserved for method signatures. I sometimes browse through the [tag:signature] to fish out questions that belong to [tag:digital-signature] but I sometimes also find email signature related questions (for which there is no specific tag, to my knowledge).

Comment: Did you ever find out a solution to this? We're experiencing the exact same thing, and Outlook is tagging our emails as spam.

Comment: @Horen Same thing here. Did you find anything about this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not

Comment: Would love to find a resolution for this. We're seeing the same issue.